# npx create-react-app is taking too long. Installed nodejs latest version, npm latest version

Tags: node.js, reactjs

this is what I'm getting in the terminal for about an hour

```
PS C:\Users\91725\Desktop\react-app> npx create-react-app myapp

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\91725\Desktop\react-app\myapp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

[#######...........] \ idealTree:terser-webpack-plugin: sill fetch manifest ajv-keywords@^3.5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar kind of issue for so long, I used `yarn create-react-app my-app` and it worked for me!

Comment: ok, but in my case it was due to slow internet connection